# Can I use Firebase for now?

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am in the process of developing an android product review app using Firebase for database. However, I am concerned about performance and scale-ability. So I've the following 2 questions?

1. Is Firebase good enough for say 10-20k customers?
2. Is it possible to later transfer my "data" and user accounts from firebase to a relational DB on AWS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the answer to the first question is yes. You can handle that much of customers. But, the service won't be free. You might have to pay some money.

According to my knowledge answer is yes for the second question. If you consider a traditional way, you can export data from firebase and write a script to update them to AWS.

The next way is using AWS congnito. try these below links

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html

Hope these will help you

Comment: Thanks Charuka. Regarding the answer to first question, how efficient is Firebase with handing so many customers? I mean does Firebase gets slow with such number of customers?